# Window.Onload function not firing in IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, onload, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to create a zooming and panning app to work across all browsers. It works in all other browsers, but in IE 10- just doesn't load the image, but does redraw it when I click on canvas to zoom in. Here's the window.onload part of the code:

```
window.onload = function(){     
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    trackTransforms(ctx);
    function redraw(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.drawImage(map,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    }
    redraw();

    var lastX=canvas.width/2, lastY=canvas.height/2;
    var dragStart,dragged;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
        document.body.style.mozUserSelect = document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = document.body.style.userSelect = 'none';
        lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
        lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
        dragStart = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
        dragged = false;
    },false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
        lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
        lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
        dragged = true;
        if (dragStart){
            var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
            ctx.translate(pt.x-dragStart.x,pt.y-dragStart.y);
            redraw();
        }
    },false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(evt){
        dragStart = null;
        if (!dragged) zoom(evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1 );
    },false);

    var scaleFactor = 1.1;
    var zoom = function(clicks){
        var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
        ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
        var factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor,clicks);
        ctx.scale(factor,factor);
        ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);
        redraw();
    }

    var handleScroll = function(evt){
        var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta/40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
        if (delta) zoom(delta);
        return evt.preventDefault() && false;
    };
    canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel',handleScroll,false);
};
map.src = 'http://www.theodora.com/maps/new9/time_zones_4.jpg';
```

Comment: Are you sure the page is loaded properly? Internet Explorer sometime screw the way the page is rendered using the so-called Internet Explorer mode. You can change this behavior by forcing the browser to follow the proper mode using a php header. It's mainly useful because IE is not respecting the meta tag, even when used properly.

Comment: I tried that, but the same problem persisted. Maybe I did it wrong, I'm a beginner for all of this...

Comment: I noticed sometime IE is not consistent by how it deal with it. Put this bit of code in your php file;
<?php header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1"); ?>

It will force IE to work properly.

Check this; http://stacigh.com/2012/07/forcing-ie-edge-and-chrome-frame-using-php/

Comment: Alright so I tried adding the php header to my file and when you first open it in IE 10, it loads the image initially and you can go about zooming and panning- however, when you refresh the page, it doesn't load the image again and if you zoom in, then it redraws it. Any idea, why?

Comment: maybe trying for the dom to be fully loaded before doing it would help.